# How to output mongodb collections in nodejs app to get them in response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I am using Cloude 9 environment for developing my nodejs app. In that I have written code to connect to mongodb database. I am successfully connecting to database and adding record to collection.

Now I want to send the collection info in return. But using `res.send(collectionInfo);` is not working.

Let me know how should I achieve this

Below is the code of my server.js file

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var async = require('async');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();

var helpers = require('express-helpers')

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var db;

helpers(app);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
var server = http.Server(app);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function () {
    var addr = server.address();
    console.log("Chat server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));

// MongoDB Connection
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next();
})

app.get('/monogdb', function (req, res) {
    res.render('monogdb.ejs');
});

app.post('/ajax-mongo-connect', function (req, res) {
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
    mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{

            var db = mongoClient.db("mydb");
            db.createCollection("students", { name : req.body.nm, description : req.body.desc, location : req.body.loc } );
            console.log('database connected',db);
            var collectionInfo = db.collection("students");
            mongoClient.close();
            //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(collectionInfo);

        }
    })
})
```

As per @Roman Sachenko answer, I have tried to use
`res.send(collectionInfo.toJSON());` but it is giving below error

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:299 
throw err; 
^ 
TypeError: Object #<Collection> has no method 'toJSON' 
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:66:41 
at MongoClient.open
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:103:5) 
 at Db.open (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:296:11) 
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

and using `res.send({data: collectionInfo});` gives error

```
home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:299                                                                                                 
throw err;                                                                                                                                              
     ^                                                                                                                                                 
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON                                                                                                                  
at Object.stringify (native)                                                                                                                                  
at ServerResponse.res.json (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:185:19)                                                               
at ServerResponse.res.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:117:21)                                                               
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:67:21                                                                                                                     
at MongoClient.open (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:103:5)                                                           
at Db.open (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:296:11)                                                                             
at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Comment: You should be good with process.env.PORT but just note the you can only make ports 8080, 8081, and 8082 publicly accessible on Cloud9 so make sure your errors aren't related to port usage.

Comment: Do you tried to do what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: An Important point, why are you returning the collection? You should execute something after call the collection, for example an insert or a delete... When you call the Collection function, basically the mongodb return a structure that is prepared to execute an operation in the DB.
I suggest you to review your code. If you need more help, I'm here ;)

Comment: The code that @roman-sachenko suggested will never work because is a code for Mongoose framework, you are using the MongDB native framework.

Comment: @mujaffars I updated my answer. Take a look there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return this: `res.status(200).json({'myCollection' : collectionInfo});`.

You can find more details about express response [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res)

**Update:**

After you explain the details, take a look at the code below:

```
app.post('/ajax-mongo-connect', function (req, res) {
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
    mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({message : 'OMG, an error occurred'});
        }else{
            var db = mongoClient.db("mydb");
            db.createCollection("students", { name : req.body.nm, description : req.body.desc, location : req.body.loc } );
            console.log('database connected',db);
            var collectionInfo = db.collection("students");
            // Here we will find all students
            collectionInfo.find({}).toArray(function(err, students) {
               // so now, we can return all students to the screen.
               res.status(200).json({'myCollection' : students});
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Cheers!

Comment: Basically I need to return records stored in collection, To display them in listing. I have also tried your code "res.status(200).json({'myCollection' : collectionInfo});" but by using this also Page Hangs. I think we are not sending back any response so that callback waiting for response and page becomes unresponsive.

Nevertheless let me know how should I return collection records, So that I can iterate them and display in Table listing format.

Answer (score 0):

## Mongoose ODM

First of all I would like to recommend you using Mongoose ODM:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose

So you will make you work with database much easier.

Basically it returns (Mongoose) normal object as results, but in case of issues you may try to use `toObject()` or `toJSON()` or as it mentioned create own object like `{data: mongoCollection}`

Examples:

```
res.send(collectionInfo.toObject());
res.send(collectionInfo.toJSON());
res.send({data: collectionInfo});
```

Please refer to the link in case of questions:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON

## Native Driver

As for native driver, it also should return normally-constructed object, but according to issues I faced with in the past, JSON.stringify always helps if you set headers manually.

You may also check the contents of your entity. So you can just output it by `console.log(collectionInfo);`

Then just make sure that there is correct object inside.
And according to results you can take actions like:

- `res.send(JSON.stringify(collectionInfo)) //set headers manually`
- `res.json(JSON.stringify(collectionInfo)) //you don't need to set headers`

At least you will know what exactly is inside of collectionInfo. I think it will be enough to investigate the issue.

Comment: I have tried res.send(collectionInfo.toJSON()); and res.send({data: collectionInfo}); but it is not working and gives error. I have updated question and added details about error please check.

Comment: @roman-sachenko Note that he is using the MongoDB native driver to communicate with the DB, the code that you suggested is for Mongoose framework and not for the native driver. Please, correct your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can view circular JSON objects by doing this in node.js:

```
 const util = require('util') // Native node module

 util.inspect(circularObj)
```

You can call it from anywhere in the code, so it's very versatile.